# Can I intercept audio on a rooted Android?

Tags: android, linux, audio

I understand it is not possible to redirect the audio output from a pre-existing Android app - say Spotify - to a USB sound card or a file for instance. I believe this may have had something to do with privacy and recording telephone calls.

I do not understand Linux very well but know that it is very flexible and often read about piping the output of one program to the input of another. I also see that in the dev directory of some Androids some “files” with names like “audio”.

My question is - do any of these correspond to the raw audio output and if the tablet/phone was rooted could the stream be intercepted with some Linux magic?

My motivation is to provide a higher quality audio output than the basic speaker / headphone / bluetooth options.

Comment: There are already Android phones on the market that support USB audio (plug in a USB DAC and it should be routed to automatically, just as if you had plugged in a 3.5mm headset). The output you'll get will typically be limited to 48 kHz 16-bit stereo, though.

Comment: Thanks Michael - do you know a make or model this applies to? Martin

Comment: I've only tested it myself on Sony phones; specifically the XPeria Z/ZL. It also works on the XPeria V and TL, _as far as I can recall_. Supposedly, some Samsung phones also has USB audio support, but I don't know which models specifically. Keep in mind that you'll most likely need a USB-B to USB-microA adapter. I also found that accessories that drew large amounts of power from the phone would work badly or not at all. That shouldn't be a problem with a USB DAC since they often have their own power supply.

Comment: Thanks again - though I would still like to know if there is an answer to the technical side of this question.

Comment: Update - I tested an Xperia Z tablet and yes it works with an unbranded USB soundcard but not with a Lindy USB 2.0 Audio Adapter - it almost works the tablet responds to the volume control on the Lindy but no sound.

Comment: There used to be a bug on the Z/ZL phones (not sure how much the tablet audio code differs) which caused a really low / inaudible playback volume for some USB audio accessories (this is a separate volume from Android's stream volume, so cranking Android's music volume up to the max wouldn't help). I seem to recall that a fix was made, but I'm not sure when it was integrated or for which products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you might be able to hack something together. But the audio implementation on a particular handset is completely up to the manufacturer so there is no guarantee. It is unlikely to be as simple as you think. There is no one-line command line magic for it.

Android doesn't use the usual Linux ALSA user space code so you can not generalize from Linux and say "if I can do it in Linux I can do it on rooted Android".

I think that some Android implementations use TinyALSA but this is not a requirement. If this is the case you might be able to recompile TinyALSA with your own intercept logic or interpose your device some other way. Similarly if you are running an Android mod built from source you could modify it to intercept the audio at other levels such as in the Audio Flinger or at the interface to the HAL. This is less practical if you are just using a rooted device since manufacturers often modify system elements with customization that might make it difficult for you to interpose and intercept (just because you don't know what to substitute if the API has been modified).

Much of the info in this answer I gleaned from reading the [Andraudio mailing list](http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio). You can check the archives to learn more.

Comment: Hi Ross - thanks. That was useful and led me to this [list of compatible androids and souncards](http://www.head-fi.org/t/595071/android-phones-and-usb-dacs/2763) I think my next step will be to try and root a Nexus 7 - my preferred Android for this - Martin